# How to prevent flashes sub-menu on click on mobile with React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

**EDIT**
After refactor my code, and be careful to use useState in thinking about next render, I've a new problem, my sub-menu flashes on mobile inspector on click even with preventDefault() method.

---

*previous issue* :

Info: *li* is one of main menu.
While I hover over the li, it works but from the moment I click on it, it breaks down.
i.e that all is reversed, when I leave my cursor from li, the sub-menu appears, and if I hover again, it disappears.

I use React.js, Next.js and TailWind.

*updated code*

```js
function MenuItems({title, link, hasSubMenu}) {
    const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

    function toggleHoverState() {
        setHover(!isHover);
        handleDisplayOfSubNav();
    }

    function handleDisplayOfSubNav() {
        if (!isHover && !isOpen) {
            setOpen(true);
        } else if (isHover && isOpen) {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    }

    const menuItemsClasses; // ... lots of css classes list

    if (hasSubMenu) {
        return (
            <li
                onPointerEnter={
                    (e) => {
                        toggleHoverState();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                onPointerLeave={
                    (e) => {
                        toggleHoverState();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            >
                <h3 className={`${menuItemsClasses}`}>
                    {title}
                    // a svg
                </h3>
                // a svg
                
                <ul className={`${isOpen ? "block" : "hidden"} md:absolute md:bg-primary md:border-secondary md:border-4 rounded-3xl -translate-y-2`} >
                    {
                        [...Array(hasSubMenu.length)].map((e, i) => (
                            <li key={i}>
                                <Link href={link} className={`${menuItemsClasses} text-sm ${hasSubMenu[i].hasSubMenu ? "underline" : "no-underline"}`}>
                                    {hasSubMenu[i].title}
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <li>
                <Link href={link} className={menuItemsClasses}>{title}</Link>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using double events, mouseOver will fire at the same time enter will. 
Try using onPointerEnter, onPointerLeave events.

Comment: I didn't know onPointer events, it's more concise.
After refactor my code with this events type [and reminded me that hooks in react becomes effectives to next render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069332/20089162), I've new problem. When I click in mobile inspector, my sub-menu flashes even with preventDefault(). Do you know how to fix that ?